# How to get Sub string Using Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am user sql server 2008 i need sub string between two character.That is the String are

```
String 
ABCD/23/L19
ABD/3/L12
BCD/23/L15
WBCD/54/L12
ABCD/8/L15
```

And My Result would be like this.

```
Desired_String
23
3
23
54
8
```

in this case i want string between '/'.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `SUBSTRING`, `CHAR_INDEX` and `REVERSE` should be enough

Comment: how to get CHAR_INDEX  of second slash(/)?

Comment: With the help of `REVERSE`, obviously. You may need `LEN` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`.

**Query**

```
select string, substring(string, charindex('/', string, 1) + 1, 
          (len(string) - charindex('/', string, 1) - 
          charindex('/', reverse(string), 1))) as num
from your_table_name;
```

**[Demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/635508/how-to-get-sub-string-using-sql-server-2008)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(t.string, t1.i + 1, t2.i - t1.i - 1)
FROM mytable AS t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/', t.string)) AS t1(i)
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/', t.string, t1.i + 1)) AS t2(i)
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/WVABM60774)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing

```
DECLARE @X VARCHAR(50)='WBCD/54/L12';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@X, CHARINDEX('/', @X, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', @X, CHARINDEX('/', @X, 1) + 1) - CHARINDEX('/', @X, 1) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(50)='WBCD/54/L12'
SELECT @STRING=RIGHT(@STRING,CHARINDEX('/',@STRING)+1)
SELECT LEFT(@STRING,CHARINDEX('/',@STRING)-1)
```